# Selenium RC scripts are too slow .Not able to identify

Tags: java

Selenium RC scripts run too slow. Can someone help me on this..
Here are my configurations...
OS: Win7(x64)
Browser: IE9
Selenium RC version:2.25

Also I am using selenium-server.jar file to connect to selenium server and my script is not not Webdriver based as I am new to selenium RC.

What can I do for this?

Answer (score 1):

Selenium starts a browser with its hole rendering-engine, therefore it is quite slow (rendering the web site needs its time)

Maybe you should consider using something different for testing.

I use HtmlUnit http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/
which does not render anything. But you will need some programming skills to use it.

Comment: But I can only use Selenium RC for testing.There is no other alternative for me.Someone please suggest me.

Comment: Which requirements force you to use Selenium?